# Cannot figure out why form error messages are cleared on resubmission

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

On first submit the error messages come up. In order to clear out error messages for correct values, I created a loop to clear out any spans on those labels, with the thinking that ALL messages would be cleared out, then run through the error checking again and re-apply the error messages.

Even if I return false on the loop to clear out the error messages it just refreshes the page. And the code does not appear to make it past that point and go through the standard error checking.

```
var label = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var spanMatch = false;

//attempting to remove any span tags once it's resubmitted 
    for (var k=0; k<label.length; k++) {

    if (label.childNodes = span[1]) {
        label.removeChild.span[1];
        spanMatch = true;       
        }
    }       
    if (spanMatch) {return false;}

    var match = false;

//created a single loop so it would check all without return false until all were checked
    for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {

        if (!loanVal.match(regexOne)) {         
        wholeError(obj.loanAmt.name);
        match = true;   
        }
        if (!interestVal.match(regexTwo)){
        floatError(obj.interest.name);
        match = true;   
        }

        if (!periodVal.match(regexOne)) {           
        wholeError(obj.period.name);
        match = true;   
        }

    }
    if (match) {return false;}


    else {alert("Something is right");}  
}
```

I hope that is enough code to tell where the problem is. Here's a link to this problem online: http://russet.wccnet.edu/~sfloyd/inp271/php-js-project/loan-calc/index.php

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using some library to validate your forms like [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/) if you can't do it yourself?

Comment: Your description is a little bit unclear to me. If you return `false` in the first loop (clearing the `span` elements), the code won't go further, because `return` ends execution of a function. Please add some code showing how you call the function you've already posted.

Comment: Yes, very true. I stuck that in there to see what would happen, however even with that `false` in there the form still submits.